# How to export collections and sub collections together from firestore to excel or bigquery table?

Tags: json, excel, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

In cloud firestore, I have a 'users' collection which contains all the ids of my users. Each user id has a 'Favorite Routes' sub-collection in which the identifier of each Favorite route is found and each Favorite route id has all the details of the favorite routes.
After several tries, I can't export everything so that we can see clearly which user has what as favorite routes.
More clearly, I can't export a collection with the sub collections that go with it.
I want to do this export and create a table in bigquery to see this either in google data studio or in the form of an excel table.

I tried to do this : 
gcloud firestore export gs://exportation-users/export-27-05-2020 --collection-ids=utilisateurs,trajetsFavoris

This make the export but impossible to create table into bigquery or to create a excel file.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import), you can use the `gcloud firestore export` command to export collection and sub-collections to a Cloud bucket. Within this command, as you described above, you can select the collections and sub-collections with the `--collection-ids` flag. In addition, it is a good practice to use `--async` flag when exporting large tables.

After having exported your data to the specified bucket, you can load the data to BigQuery, using `bq load` command, [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#bq). For each collection and/or sub-collection will have a table, so execute it twice (in your case you will be importing 1 collection and 1 sub-collection). The syntax would be as follows:

```
bq --location=US load \
--source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP \
mydataset.book_data \
gs://mybucket/20180228T1256/default_namespace/kind_Book/default_namespace_kind_Book.export_metadata
```

I would like to point that `--source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP` is mandatory, and it is the format for a Firestore export. All the other fields should be changed according to your environment.

Lastly, I must point that each document in Firestore have unique keys that contain important information about the data. Among these keys, you have ***key**.name* which stores the parent document key and it can used to join the collection with its respective sub-collection.

Lastly, you can also use Cloud Functions in order to create the bucket, export the data to the bucket and import the data to BigQuery, an example can be found [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/modern-data-pipeline-firestore-bigquery-dataflow-templates/index.html?index=..%2F..next17#0).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know if it is possible to have the collection and the subcollection together in a table

Comment: @OrenCohen,  yes, it is. You select the collection and subcollection to load in 2 different tables in BigQuery. Than you can use the table's [keys](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#firestore_key_properties) to join the collection with its respective subcollection. I also found another tutorial which might be helpfulm [link](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/exporting-data-firebase-firestore-bigquery/). Please do not forget to accept and upvote the answer.